# PhpStorm 6 does not always show PHP structure

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 6 for web development. I have noticed that PhpStorm quite frequently never shows the PHP Structure in the PHP Structure window. This is very annoying and almost makes the IDE useless. The window shows the spinning icon and never finishes. The code I am working on is a couple hundred lines so this should not take more than a second or two to scan and display (never had this issue in eclipse). I am wondering if there is some sort setting that I am missing or is this a bug the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem in PHP Storm 7.1, accepted solution also fixed this version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happened in older versions of PHPStorm. In big project try: File>Invalidate Caches and then restart the IDE.

Comment: Fixes same problem in 7.1 as well